# Chaining first js function to second js function, when second one delays the return value

Tags: javascript

Here is what I am trying to do. Not successful and gives out error. Is it possible to delay the return value, and chain functions such that 2nd one delays the return value?

```
 a().b() 

function a( )
{
    var self=this;

      setTimeout( function(){ return self },2000);

      return null; //<<<<< this causes problem
}

function b()
{
    trace("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this sort of thing with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) and (optionally) [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

Something like:

```js
function a() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('the return value'), 2000);
  })
}

function b(value) {
  console.log(`from b: ${value}`);
}

a().then(b);
```

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. Fixed.